# Javascript DOM "this" Object is incorrect

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there anybody who can explain the followig error message? 
I'm trying to get simple informations about mutiple divs while one of them throws this error.

> Ignoring get or set of property that has [LenientThis] because the "this" object is incorrect. (script.js:3288)

```
resource://gre/modules/devtools/server/actors/script.js
```

The Code i'm using is:

```
var elem = document.getElementById(id);
ret['left'] = Math.round(elem.offsetLeft); //elem.offsetLeft returns null
```

I haven't seen such an error before and can't find any information about this problem. It would be great if somebody could tell me, what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: That's an error in Firefox' devtools. It shouldn't have anything to do with your code.

Comment: If you want help with a `this` error, then you will have to show the actual line where the error occurs, the enclosing function and the caller of that function.  What you have shown in your question so far does not indicate any use of `this`.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=860312

Comment: I got a similar error because I was dealing with a sorted object from the original that was in the hierarchy of an event object. I forget that I've sorted it into another object and make a recursive function. That was my error, but it certainly can have something to do with the scope

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1298830

Answer (score 28, accepted):

@felix-king is correct, this is a firefox devtools errors.  It usually happens when you inspect an object and you open a base prototype tree node lower than the type of the instance you are inspecting.  So this explains the "this" error problem that @jfriend00 refers to in the comment, even though you don't reference "this" in your code, the Inspector does.

Comment: Can you explain more about the "base prototype tree node lower than the type of the instance you are inspecting"? Do you mean parts of the prototype that are "inside" the object you are inspecting? Why would this cause an error, couldn't the dev tools just get the `this` of that inner object? I got this when I inspected a jQuery object, and opened the HTML node inside of it.

Comment: Looks it has already been reported to Mozilla. See [#1298830 in Mozilla Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1298830).